# How can I redraw a View after a TouchEvent?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view

I subclassed `View` to get an View on which the user can "draw" with his fingers. I implemented the Interface `View.OnTouchListener`.

How can I trigger within the `onTouch` method the redraw of the View? Do I need to implement a Thread / Runnable? I thought that `invalidate()` triggers the redraw, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call this.invalidate in the onTouchEvent method of your view, it really should work **unless you're not doing the proper thing in your onDraw method.** Make sure you're referencing to the right canvas an draw the thing in your overridden onDraw method instead of for example the constructor.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I forgot to register the OnTouchListener: `this.setOnTouchListener(this);` Now it works fine!